# Compare two files .txt - Python

Tags: python, compare

Can you help me?

I have two files .txt with differences between  them and I need to compare them and say what the difference is and where it's.

I made a simple code but still didn't answer me.

**File1:**

```
123
1234
12345           
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
1234567890
saída do arquivo
```

**File2:**

```
123
1234
12345
123456          
1234567
12345678
123456789
1234567890
fim de arquivo
```

> The program should return:

```
File1: saída do arquivo - line 9

File2: fim de arquivo - line 9
```

My code:

```
test_lines = open('teste1.txt').readlines()
correct_lines = open('teste2.txt').readlines()

for test, correct in zip(test_lines, correct_lines):
    if test != correct:
        print (("Oh no! Expected %r; got %r." )% (correct, test));
        break
    else:
        len_diff = len(test_lines) - len(correct_lines)
        if len_diff > 0:
            print ("Test file had too much data.")
        elif len_diff < 0:
            print ("Test file had too little data.")
        else:
            print ("Everything was correct!")

    lista_final = list(set(test_lines) - set(correct_lines))

print(lista_final)
```

> What it actually returns:

```
['12345\t\t\t\n', '123456\n', 'saída do arquivo']
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - I doubt that you have a well defined characterization of what kind of differences your algorithm should return. Why is _arquivo_ part of the returned difference when it is equal in both files? Or should the program return all the rest of every line from any differnece found on? IMO you should clarify your requirements, for yourself and for the people you ask here.

Answer (score 0):

In your file, there are extra spaces and tabs after the second entry
[image: screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot.
That's why you are getting unexpected results